# Can we able reset throttling limit for testing purpose

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to set the custom throttling limit for testing purpose. Currently as per guidline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling,  it is "10,000 API requests in a 10 minute period" for "Outlook service limits".

1. For testing purpose can I reset it to "100 API requests in a 10 minute period"?
2. In admin account where I have configure the platform, can I get information of throttling limit exceed notification?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way you can customize throttling. You can raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may develop it in the future. You can handle the throttling using Retry-After header according to this [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling) .

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity thank you for confirmation.

Comment: Is their any way to get throttling notification on admin account?

Comment: You can handle the throttling as I said above using Retry-After header. Graph server doesn't notify directly, you can write your code to send email to your admin when there is a status 429 in your application.

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can customize throttling. You can raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may develop it in the future. You can handle the throttling using Retry-After header according to this [public document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling).

Graph server doesn't notify directly, you can write your own code to send email to your admin when there is a status 429 in your application.